# Plot multiple time-series data with different date/time in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have been collecting some server delay metrics for different periods under different configurations and I need to represent my data in a graph.

Each data-set is collected at a different time for a period of 30 minutes (+/- 2min). Data-sets are big (~ 15k records each).

I need to plot a line chart in excel where each line represents a time-series. After refinement I have three columns (epoch timestamp, latency and generated HH:MM:SS time), Sample below.

```
timeStamp       Latency     Time
1511476257126   3307    22:30:57
1511476257391   3045    22:30:57
1511476257693   2741    22:30:58
1511476257994   2442    22:30:58
1511476259193   1241    22:30:59
1511476259492   945     22:30:59
1511476259791   630     22:31:00
1511476261492   296     22:31:01
1511476261494   314     22:31:01
1511476261514   343     22:31:02
1511476263481   294     22:31:03
1511476263483   298     22:31:03
1511476263484   296     22:31:03
1511476263492   938     22:31:03
1511476263494   300     22:31:03
1511476263507   288     22:31:04
1511476263556   385     22:31:04
1511476264300   301     22:31:04
1511476264347   312     22:31:04
1511476264361   293     22:31:04
```

How should I normalize such data to plot a time-series where all data-sets are aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to normalize the data by seconds, I created an extra column, that using timeStamp generates the second value. Either using `=MIN(A:A)` where `A:A` is the timeStamp column; to get the start time, or by statically setting the minimum value (to avoid heavy computation on large datasets).

The extra column will use `=FLOOR.MATH(([@timeStamp]/1000)-(MIN(A:A)/1000))`, alternatively, to get the value in minutes `=FLOOR.MATH(([@timeStamp]/1000)-(MIN(A:A)/1000))/60`.

Now my table looks like this:

```
timeStamp   Latency Time
1511464884268   175 0
1511464886024   396 1
1511464886427   402 2
1511464886831   309 2
1511464887142   404 2
1511464887547   306 3
1511464887855   305 3
1511464888162   309 3
1511464888475   403 4
1511464888879   305 4
1511464889186   305 4
1511464889492   306 5
1511464889799   412 5
```

Finally, from **Insert** > **PivotTable** select the two columns, then enable both fields, set *Time* as a **Row**, and *Latency* in **Values** and edit it to Average over values.

Now I have grouped each unit time (s) into one row with average latency, from here, plot all normalized tables into one chart.

Sample output

```
0   2152.666667
1   1364
2   404.4615385
3   346.1153846
4   342.90625
5   422.125
6   355.375
7   358.2156863
8   343.7868852
9   326.6323529
10  373.4225352
11  339.3684211
12  387.1914894
13  367.9545455
14  337.7978723
15  326.0181818
```